# Compile command in buildbot to generate the python executable file

Tags: python, windows, buildbot

There are lots of articles talking about how to create an executable (.exe) file from Python script on Windows from command line (by using py2exe, etc.).  However, I have not had any luck finding how to make buildbot tool automatically create the executable file from Python script every time it runs.

I am running buildbot tool on Windows XP.

Is there a compile command to configure the master.cfg in buildbot to generate the python .exe file?

Comment: py2exe is just a command line tool, I imagine you can call it from buildbot like you could call any other external tool.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! You gave me a hint what to look for.  I am new to programming and build tool.  Thought that I would give Python a try.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Ross suggested, py2exe is a commmand line tool, that can be run just like any other, using [`ShellCommand`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#shellcommand).

On the other hand, it would seen to make sense to add the ability to create a exe using py2exe to your build system, and then invoke it that way from buildbot. This has the advantage that developers and users can then get the exact same behavior as the buildbot, on their local machines.